# Excel Column Matching then select id of a column

Tags: excel

I have problem that I cant solve. I need to select Preceding id from  one column by matching with other like this

```
id  gname            id2     gname2
1   Cefaclor                 Cefaclor
2   Amlodipine               Cefaclor
3   Olmesartan               Cefaclor
4   Memantine                Amlodipine
                             Olmesartan
                             Olmesartan
                             Memantine
```

and output like this

```
id  gname            id2     gname2
1   Cefaclor          1      Cefaclor
2   Amlodipine        1      Cefaclor
3   Olmesartan        1      Cefaclor
4   Memantine         2      Amlodipine
                      3      Olmesartan
                      3      Olmesartan
                      4      Memantine
```

Comment: Use the Match function to find the gname row; and then the Index function to find the id

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example formula with the layout as shown in the included picture.  You would enter the formula in C2, and fill down to C8.

You will need to adjust the references according to your actual layout:

```
C2:  =INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$5,0))
```

[image]